# LINQ query to return collection of original object with a transformed property

Tags: c#, linq

I currently have working code

```
foreach (var item in list)
{
    item.Property1= SomeFunction(item.Property1);
}

return list;
```

I'd like to convert this into a LINQ query but I'm not quite sure how to. I suspect I need to use a .Select but I'm not sure how to do that properly. My attempt was to try:

```
return list.Select(r => SomeFunction(r.Property1));
```

but of course that only returned a collection of Properties whereas I want a collection of the original object with an altered property within it.

Comment: `list.ForEach(x => x.Property1 = SomeFunction(item.Property1);`??

Comment: Lina expressions are intended to be side-effect free. I think you should stick with the `foreach`.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is probably a bad idea in general, but here you go ...

You want something like `list.Select(x => { SomeFunction(x); return x; });` where `SomeFunction` is a function to transform the property you want.

Full example:

```
public class A { public int Data { get; set; } }

public void SomeFunction(A a)
{
    a.Data *= 2;
}

var listy = new List<A>() { 
    new A() { Data = 3 }, 
    new A() { Data = 5 } 
};

listy.Select(x => { SomeFunction(x); return x; })
```

output (C# Interactive shell):

```
Enumerable.WhereSelectListIterator<Submission#9.A, Submission#9.A> { Submission#9.A { Data=6 }, Submission#9.A { Data=10 } }
```

Comment: Correct. It's a bad idea. There's no guarantee that the enumeration will ever run so the objects may remain unaltered.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `list` if of type `List<>`:

`list.ForEach(x => x.Property1 = SomeFunction(item.Property1));`

But what is wrong with `foreach` anyway?